# Java generics: why can't inner interface implement from a (inner) superinterface?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface SuperInterface {
    public interface SubInterface {
        public void get();
    }
    //**More interfaces*/

}
```

this method in my Toolkit, which retrieves all objects which are instance of a certain class:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> getSome(ArrayList<Object> objects, Class<T> clazz) {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object o : objects) 
        if (clazz.isInstance(o)) 
            result.add(clazz.cast(o));
    return result;
}
```

MyClass is not really interesting, its an empty class implementing from `SuperInterface.SubInterface`

And this piece in the main:

```
ArrayList<Object> mObjects = new ArrayList<Object>() {
    {
        add(new MyClass()); //SuperInterface.SubInterface
        add(Integer.valueOf(5));
        add(new String("Hello"));
        add(new Object());
    }
};
ArrayList<SuperInterface> mSuperInterfaces = Toolkit.getSome(mObjects, SuperInterface.class); //returns a zero-sized list.
ArrayList<SuperInterface.SubInterface> mSubInterfaces = Toolkit.getSome(mObjects, SuperInterface.SubInterface.class); //returns a one-sized list
```

The first method call does not work as I hoped, the second does. Is it possible so that the first one works without explicitly putting the subinterfaces in a different file and implementing the superclass? Because *apparently the subinterfaces aren't really subinterfaces*, so I tried to make the Interface class like this:

```
public class ClassWithInterfaces {
  public interface Super { }
  public interface Sub implements Super { /**...*/ }
}
```

But apparently you can't use `implements` in an inner interface.

My question is: **Why is that**, and is there a way to accomplish what I want to achieve (inner interfaces in one file)? I don't necessarily need it, I merely want to know why it's not possible to implement in inner interfaces (yet it's possible to extend inner classes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But apparently you can't use `implements` in an inner interface.

You're looking for `extends` rather than `implements`:

```
public class ClassWithInterfaces {
  public interface Super { }
  public interface Sub extends Super { /**...*/ }
}
```

This compiles for me, and I can certainly implement both interfaces.

Since there appears to be some confusion around extending vs implementing, perhaps the following will help clear things up:

- An interface *extends* another interface.
- A class *implements* an interface.
- A class *extends* another class.

Comment: Since when is it possible to extend from an interface? I thought the keywords implements and extends where there to distinguish between abstract classes and interfaces?

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong: An interface always *extends* other interfaces, it never *implements* them. Only a class can implement things.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's actually quite logical. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java Language Specification:

- [all members of an interface (except methods) are implicitly
  static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5)
- [member interfaces are always implicitly static themselves, by
  definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1)

So here you have two reasons why you can't have "real" inner interfaces

Also, as NPE writes, an interface can never implement another interface, it can only extend it. Classes can implement interfaces and / or extend classes, interfaces can only extend interfaces. Makes perfect sense to me.